# Maven attempts to use wrong snapshot version

Tags: maven-2, snapshot

I'm trying to deploy the snapshot version of a 3rd party library to our local repo (for legacy reasons this is and old version which is no longer hosted at any online repo, and for the time being I can't replace it, hence I have to host it locally).

Now, I think I've misunderstood the SNAPSHOT-concept, so I'd be very thankful if somebody could set me straight. The jar I have is named foo-0.5.0-20090612.124.jar, and I try uploading it using maven deploy:deploy file to org.bar.foo under version 0.5.0.
The version dependency in my POM is 0.5.0-SNAPSHOT

Each time I upload the jar file to our local repo the number following the date in the filename is iterated (i.e to 125), but when I run maven install, maven attempts to download a jar with the previous number (i.e. 124).

So, is there any way of getting maven to download the correct snapshot version, or should I have no business uploading 3rd party SNAPSHOT files to our repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use case you have is fine. I believe the best practice recommended by the Maven folks is that once you are uploading a SNAPSHOT version of a jar to a shared repository, you should stop treating it as a SNAPSHOT, and instead as a release.

This makes sense because you want people to depend on ***that specific version of that artifact***. The artifact is not under active development and is not expected to change arbitrarily at any point in time and for that reason it should be considered a release. Just one to which you give your own personal fancy name, and one that someone else considered a SNAPSHOT.

When you ask for the dependency foo-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT, I don't believe Maven looks for foo-0.5.0-. I believe it literally looks for foo-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT in the repository, and that is why you are not finding it. (Not 100% sure about this though, as we don't timestamp our SNAPSHOTS. We simply continually overwrite -SNAPSHOT jars with newer versions as they are made.)

So, put foo-0.5.0-20090612.124.jar into your third party repository (which should only contain releases for the reason above). Then in your pom, reference the "released" artifact foo-0.5.0-20090612.124 explicitly, and everything should work fine.

Comment: I'll say that in essence you're right, I really have no business adding a 3rd party snapshot to my repo. The best solution was the easiest, which was to remove the SNAPSHOT tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow, you should have an artifact called `myartifact.jar` attached to a `POM` with a version of `0.5-SNAPSHOT`.

When deploying, your repository *should* change the `-SNAPSHOT` into a timestamp and update the repository metadata to reflect that this is the most current SNAPSHOT version, so that it can properly serve a SNAPSHOT request.

Do you use a repository such as [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) or [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or just a FTP/HTTP server?

Comment: Neither, just a local fileserver. This repo is purely for internal use. 

That's pretty much what I'm trying to do, though. The problem is that when I run maven install it's not searching for the correct timestamp, but an earlier one. 

Is there anything inherent in the 3rd party jar which determines its  timestamp?